# Close CustomTabs automatically in React Native

Tags: react-native, android-customtabs

I want to close CustomTabs automatically. I have added sagepay gateway in CustomTabs, its working properly but on success page its return array. I want to get that array back into app and CustomTabs would be closed. how can i get that array into app back as a response from the url that is opened in custom tabs.
code for custom tab :-

```
url = 'https://www.example.com/newsagepay/newtest.php?&customerSage='+isuerID+'&checkSage=1';

CustomTabs.openURL(url,{ toolbarColor: '#607D8B',enableUrlBarHiding: true, showPageTitle: true, enableDefaultShare: true, 
animations: ANIMATIONS_SLIDE}).then((launched: boolean) => {                                                        
    console.log(`Launched custom tabs: ${launched}`);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
});
```

Comment: can i get URL from CustomTabs in app .js file ?

Comment: how can i do this ?

Comment: how did you solve this?I used this for amazon payment gateway.Its working fine on android(tabs opened inside the app).But in IOS, the tabs opened in safari. After successful return, safari still opened in background!